# sprite kit collisions: ignore transparency?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

I am building a game with Xcode's spritekit.  Its a platform game and right now it functions well with flat ground pieces.  I was wondering if it was possible to ignore transparency in the png for collisions.  That is to say, If i have a ground piece with a curved floor and transparency filling the troughs, can i make the player walk the curves instead of a square bounding box covering the whole thing?  The only example i can find is in the Gamemaker GML language, you can do "precise" collisions such that blank space in the images do not count as part of the sprite. I can supply code if necessary but this seems like more of a conceptual question. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use + (SKPhysicsBody *)bodyWithPolygonFromPath:(CGPathRef)path;. So yes it is possible, look at the framework methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey there's a easy solution for this provided in the Apple Documentation.

```
SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];
sprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithTexture:sprite.texture size:sprite.texture.size];
```

This creates a physics body around the physical paths of the texture.

[Simulating Physics - SpriteKit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html)

Comment: Also note that bodyWithTexture:size: is available only in iOS 8.0 and later. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithTexture:size:

Answer (score 1):

It's all in how you instantiate the physicsBody of the node in question.

```
node.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:node.size];
```

is probably the easiest and most common way of making a physicsBody, but will also create the issue you've identified above, because, for all collision purposes, the node is a rectangle.

take a look at [the documentation for SKPhysicsBody](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) to see the other options available to you. PolygonFromPath and BodyWithBodies are probably the best suited for what you're doing.

Comment: http://dazchong.com/spritekit/ is a good tool to help with making CGPaths for polygon physicsBodies.

Answer (score 0):

SKPhysicsBody is the right move, just wanted to note that it does make sense to have a separate (simplified) mask-image for SKPhysicsBody to improve your performance, simplified from color and geometry standpoint, and here's the code:

```
let birdMask: UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
let pipeMask: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
//...

pipeImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "realImage")
//... size and position

let maskTexture = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: mask)
maskTexture.size = pipeImage!.size // size of texture w/ real imageNamed

pipeImage!.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
pipeImage!.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: maskTexture.texture!, size: size)        
pipeImage!.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false // disable falling down...
pipeImage!.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
pipeImage!.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
pipeImage!.physicsBody?.friction = 0
pipeImage!.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = pipeMask
pipeImage!.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = birdMask | pipeMask
pipeImage!.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = birdMask | pipeMask
```

and [more detailed example/guide](http://www.mikitamanko.com/blog/2017/05/21/how-to-add-pixel-perfect-physics-to-an-skspritenode/).