# Swift | Ignore transparent parts of sprite when detecting collisions?

Tags: swift, transparency, collision, transparent

I want to detect collisions to every part of a sprite except for the transparent parts. I found a solution for C but I can't figure out how to do it in swift.

Here's the Obj-C solution:
[sprite kit collisions: ignore transparency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22770784/sprite-kit-collisions-ignore-transparency)

Anyone have any idea?

EDIT:

Here's my function code for building the shape. I'm not sure how to set spriteName.physicsBody to the answer supplied below by another user.

```
func addTriangles() {


    center = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"images/center.png")
    center.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    center.zPosition = -1
    center.physicsBody = init!(texture centerTexture: SKTexture!, size 1.0: CGSize) -> SKPhysicsBody?
    center.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    center.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    center.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Triangle
    self.addChild(center)
    spin = clockwise
    center.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(spin))


}
```

Comment: There's Swift examples in the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithTexture:size:).

Comment: Are you talking about: init!(texture texture: SKTexture!,
         size size: CGSize) -> SKPhysicsBody? I've been trying to figure out how to use that.

Comment: Um, you do the exact same thing, but in swift...? There's no API difference, you just rewrite code in swift.

Answer (score 1):

You actually can use

```
init!(texture texture: SKTexture!, size size: CGSize) -> SKPhysicsBody?
```

to set up the collision body with the alpha channel of the texture of your sprite

However, this is not recommended because it costs a lot to simulate complicated shape's physics behaviour.

If you have a sprite with complicated shape, try to draw another simpler shape and use its texture as your physics body.

Comment: Should it be placed in my function for building the shape, and should it be set as spriteName.physics body? I'll add the function code to my original post.

Comment: @StudioSevenDesigns set it as spriteName.physics body

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely a good idea to draw a separate more simplified image for physics body (from color and geometry stand point), as for the code, it's very close from what you need:

```
let birdMask: UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
let pipeMask: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
//...

pipeImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "realImage")
//... size and position

let maskTexture = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: mask)
maskTexture.size = pipeImage!.size // size of texture w/ real imageNamed

pipeImage!.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
pipeImage!.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: maskTexture.texture!, size: size)        
pipeImage!.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false // disable falling down...
pipeImage!.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
pipeImage!.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
pipeImage!.physicsBody?.friction = 0
pipeImage!.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = pipeMask
pipeImage!.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = birdMask | pipeMask
pipeImage!.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = birdMask | pipeMask
```

Here's the [full guide how](http://www.mikitamanko.com/blog/2017/05/21/how-to-add-pixel-perfect-physics-to-an-skspritenode/) to make it